# Divide money and things equally between room mates

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, calculator, simple-functions

My friend and I spent 12730₹ in total to buy some house hold things(say some 10 items). We shared and paid equally. Now we are vacating so we have to divide the items, but my friend wants only 2 items worth 2065₹ and 1050₹. 
Other items I have to take and have to pay him that amount.
So now how much I have to pay to him.

Comment: You each paid in $\frac{12730}{2} = 6365$ and had shared usage of all items. Now you will have full usage of some items, plus or minus some amount of money: 

$2065+1050+x = 12730 - 2065-1050-x = 6365$

Comment: The mathematical answers given ensure a fair numerical division of property but this isn't a math question. Your friend only wants those two items but maybe there are items in which you are not interested. This gives you the ability to negotiate. You should be compensated for having to take all of the items he or she doesn't want and your friend should have to pay for the privilege to decide which items are worth keeping and which should be converted to cash.

Comment: David Diaz thanks for your answer. It's giving 3250

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to negotiate what the items are worth today, then settle on a payment.  If you want to say they are all worth the same today as when they were new, your friend spent $\frac {12730}2=6365$ and received items worth $3115$, so you should pay him $6365-3115=3250$.  You have received items worth $9615$, paid $6365$ to the stores and $3250$ to your friend.